# Cannot get or post anything besides login from loopback restful api

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have played around with loopback and I think it's interesting, however it seems to be very restricted, since you can't do anything besides trying to log in in the `explorer` environment.

The guides and docs was very good at getting the server up and running and I was able to create a user and login, but when trying to `get` users it throws this error:

`http://localhost:3000/api/users`

```
"error": {
"name": "Error",
"status": 401,
"message": "Authorization Required",
"statusCode": 401,
"stack": "Error: Authorization Required"
```

I see that you can set some authentication token but I have trouble figuring out how to get that (besides shouldn't it be stored in a session or so when logging in?)

The following worked very well, but that's only on the server

[loopback session no method create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115998/loopback-session-no-method-create)

Worth noting is that I have given allow access "acl" for the user so that should not be the problem.

So question is, how do I get some access?

Comment: In the explorer, after you login, you should see a response that includes an authorization header. Copy the value and paste it into the textbox at the top right of the page to store it, then any future requests you make using the explorer will send that authorization header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see that you can set some authentication token but I have trouble figuring out how to get that (besides shouldn't it be stored in a session or so when logging in?)

See this example I created on authentication and authorization: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control

> I see that you can set some authentication token but I have trouble figuring out how to get that (besides shouldn't it be stored in a session or so when logging in?)

The session mechanism is up to you to implement as LoopBack is not opinionated here. Any session handling library that works with Express will work in LoopBack.

Answer (score 0):

You can [enable authentication in your app](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#app-enableauth) by calling `app.enableAuth()` which means that you need to find where in your code this is called and remove it.